# What is the meaning of 'drunk with the power the wand had given him' in DH 3 brothers story?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, deathly-hallows

In Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows, Hermione reads [the story about the three brothers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgmEEDyeDv8&feature=youtu.be&t=3m0s). At some point the following is said about the second brother:

> "Drunk with the power that the elder wand had given him, he bragged 
>   of his invincibility."

My question is: what is the meaning of "**drunk with the power**..." ?

Does it mean he was literally drunk, and died while being so (*easy target while drunk*).

Or, was he technically sober, but metaphorically drunk, thinking he is invincible, therefore causing him to draw attention? I would imagine that if someone brags he is invincible, there would be challengers of some kind to prove him wrong, therefore killing him.

*(I am not a native English speaker, so it sounded quite ambiguous to me.)*

Comment: This would be more appropriate on English Language Learners SE.

Comment: "Drunk with power" is a common English expression, see [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090505082927AAWQ8Ny) for some attempts to convey the meaning.

Comment: Because the movies are nonsense

Comment: This seems like more of a fit for ELU. http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is solely about interpreting a metaphor in a story, it has nothing to do with SF&F

Answer (score 7):

In this case, 'drunk with power' is just another form of 'mad with power'.  He had the world's greatest wand, making him the most powerful wizard ever.  He wasn't actually drunk, just really over-confident of his powers and abilities.

Answer (score 4):

This line is from the film version of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*:

> Drunk with the power that the Elder Wand had given him, he bragged of
> his invincibility.

In this case, he was so convinced that the Elder Wand made him unbeatable that he claimed that no one could defeat him. Essentially, the power made him act as if he were drunk, i.e. foolishly.

In the book, it is more clear:

> Leaving his enemy dead upon the floor, the oldest brother proceeded to
> an inn, where he boasted loudly of the powerful wand he had snatched
> from Death himself, and of how it made him invincible.
>
> *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*

Indeed, he did later get *literally* drunk:

> That very night, another wizard crept upon the oldest brother as he
> lay, wine-sodden, upon his bed.
>
> *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*

This is not, however, what the quote references.

Comment: It's too bad you quoted the movie. And first, to boot.. -1 for using the movie as equivalent to book canon. :)

Comment: The question is asking about a line from the movie, how was he supposed to answer the question without referring to the movie...

Comment: @Slytherincess The quote that the OP was referring to is *from* the movie. That's why I had to address it first. I established the superiority of the book canon later on! I know that JKR is the one true way. Please reverse the Slytherincess seal of disapproval ! :)